# dcm4chee | Docker deployment | How to import my own ssl certificate to wildfly

Tags: ssl, wildfly, keystore, dcm4che

I've implemented dcm4chee via docker-compose as described here (https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Run-minimum-set-of-archive-services-on-a-single-host)

I've successfully deployed it and there are 3 containers up and running (ldap & Postgres & Arc) now. however, when I access the application with https over port 8443 it gives me certificate error, so I want to import my own domain's ssl certificate to wildfly server and activate it.
I have these files fullchain.pem and privkey.pem and I converted them to keystore using this command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out temp-keystore.pkcs12
```

I managed to create a user and accessed the Administration console of wildfly, can I do this there?

What should I do to achieve the followings:

1. import and activate my own ssl certificate.
2. build the container image with those modifications.

Converted the certificate to keystore formate, copied it to the standalone/configuration directory and tried with the edit in security-realms in standalone.xml file.